# Why when i randomly select a number to be put into a list it always picks the same starting number?

Tags: python, list, random

This is the code. I'm learning Python and I tried writing a Blackjack script that can calculate the odds of ending up with an X sized hand while having 21 or below. The code is supposed to keep appending random cards out of the deck until it reaches a set amount of cards. (I know decks aren't usually infinite, it's just an experiment)

If it goes over 21 before X amount of cards in hand it discards the hand and starts a new hand.

But for some reason every time it starts a new hand that hand list starts with the same first integer as all previous hands like this:

Can someone please explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

```
[8, 3, 2, 6, 2]
[8, 2, 3, 2, 5]
[8, 2, 2, 4, 3]
[8, 6, 2, 2, 2]
[8, 2, 2, 2, 7]
[8, 4, 5, 2, 2]
[8, 5, 2, 2, 2]
[8, 2, 2, 2, 6]
[8, 2, 2, 6, 3]
[8, 3, 6, 2, 2]
[8, 6, 2, 2]
total amount of hands: 1020
the percentage of 7 card hands that total 21 or less is 1 in 10.2
```

```
import random

card_deck = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]

def blackjack_tracker(deck):

    hand = []
    trackers = 0
    count = 0
    ace = 0
    x = 0

    while trackers <10:

        if len(hand) < 7:
            hand.append(random.choice(deck))

            if len(hand) == 7 and sum(hand) <= 21:
                print(hand)
                hand.pop(all(hand))
                trackers += 1
                count += 1

            elif len(hand) == 7 and sum(hand) > 21:
                hand.pop(all(hand))
                count += 1
            



    print(hand)
    print('total amount of hands: {}'.format(count))
    print('the percentage of 7 card hands that total 21 or less is 1 in {}'.format(count/10))

blackjack_tracker(card_deck)
```

Comment: I'm not sure why (luck?), but a simpler approach would be to simply use `hand = random.choices(card_deck, k=7)`. Note that to really simulate Blackjack, you would stop adding cards to the hand as soon as the sum reaches 21 (if not sooner).

Comment: Are you using `random.seed()` anywhere?

Comment: my guess is that `hand.pop(all(hand))` - probably doesn't do what you expect it to do

Comment: @chepner Thanks, that does what I wanted but for some reason the very last hand always has one value less than the others like this:  [7, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4]
[2, 2, 6, 3, 4, 4]
[3, 7, 2, 4, 3, 2]
[3, 2, 4, 3, 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that you use for "it discards the hand and starts a new hand" is:

```
hand.pop(all(hand))
```

which doesn't discard the whole hand (the meaning of this expression is explained later).

You should use either:

```
hand.clear()
```

or

```
hand = []
```

Integesting is the meaning of the `hand.pop(all(hand))` method. Because what it really does is popping the second element of the non-empty array.

Because `all(hand)` always returns True and `hand.pop(True)` is being cast to `hand.pop(1)` and it removes the element at position 1 from the array.

That's the reason the element in position '0' is never touched - because you never remove it.